# Getting error: Unable to fetch access token in Watson Assistant?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am unable to launch my `Watson Assistant` and when I launch it, I am getting this error "`Unable to fetch access token`"?

Comment: Can you add more details like what steps you followed and where it is failing?